# My 3D plot of a Klein bottle doesn't look right

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have found the following parametrisation for a Klein bottle:

```
a = 6 Cos[2 u] (1 + Sin[u]);
b = 16 Sin[u];
c = 4 (1 - Cos[u]/2);
fx = If[Pi < u <= 0, a + c Cos[v + Pi], a + c Cos[u] Cos[v]];
fy = If[Pi < u < 2 Pi, b, b + c Sin[u] ];
fz = c Sin[v];
```

I am trying to plot it using

```
ParametricPlot3D[{fx, fy, fz}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

but the result is not quite the Klein bottle.

[image]

The reference I am using is [this one](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=6CGod4o7yf8C&pg=PA141) (page 141) where you can see the same parameterization.

1. Any ideas why it does not work with me?
2. Also how can I change the colours of the surface to be as in the book?

Comment: Your transcription of the code from your source is incorrect. As soon as you use the 1:1 code, the result is comparable. The colors can be dealt with by `PlotTheme -> "Classic"`.

Comment: Hi, I apologize for this.

Comment: Not to worry,  have fun!

Comment: FWIW: `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "KleinBottle"}]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's my slight simplification of the Klein bottle parametric equations. I believe the original parametrization is due to Stewart Dickson (whose depiction of the bottle was in the "Graphics Gallery" of the old versions of *The Mathematica Book*).

```
ParametricPlot3D[{6 Cos[u] (1 + Sin[u]), 16 Sin[u], 0} + 2 (2 - Cos[u])
                 {Cos[Clip[u, {0, π}]] Cos[v], Sin[Clip[u, {0, π}]] Cos[v], Sin[v]},
                 {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, 2 π}, Lighting -> "Classic", Mesh -> False,
                 PlotStyle -> Opacity[2/3, ColorData["Legacy", "AliceBlue"]]]
```

[image: translucent Klein bottle]

I have elected to use translucency instead to reveal the inner structure of the bottle. If you want to cut the bottle, just restrict the parameter ranges, like so:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{6 Cos[u] (1 + Sin[u]), 16 Sin[u], 0} + 2 (2 - Cos[u])
                 {Cos[Clip[u, {0, π}]] Cos[v], Sin[Clip[u, {0, π}]] Cos[v], Sin[v]},
                 {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, π, 2 π}, Mesh -> False, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: half a bottle]

(Have a look at [Franzoni's article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/noti880) as well to see other possible variations.)

Comment: Is this immersed image of the Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ some sort of projection of an embedding of the Klein bottle into $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: Not near my notes right now, but I recall this just follows Thomas Banchoff's procedure to make a surface with the required topology, and not necessarily derived from an $\mathbb R^4$ embedding.

Answer (score 10):

**Description**

For fun, thought I give it a try. Below is an example of my attempt to `Plot` Kleins bottle.

**Code**

```
klein[u_, v_] := Module[{
   bx = 6 Cos[u] (1 + Sin[u]),
   by = 16 Sin[u],
   rad = 4 (1 - Cos[u]/2),
   X, Y, Z},
  X = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, bx + rad Cos[v + Pi], bx + rad Cos[u] Cos[v]];
  Y = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, by, by + rad Sin[u] Cos[v]];
  Z = rad Sin[v];
  {X, Y, Z}
  ]

ParametricPlot3D[klein[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

**Output**

[image: klein bottle]

Comment: thanks a lot. This is very nice and I have to admit I do not know to plot such things my self. May I ask if there is a way to cut the bottle in half (and in different angles) in order to see what it looks like "inside"? I want to use it to show to some students that there is a Mobius band inside.

Answer (score 9):

This is just to give a solution based on minimal correction of the OP's code.

```
a[u_] := 6 Cos[u] (1 + Sin[u])
b[u_] := 16 Sin[u]
c[u_] := 4 (1 - Cos[u]/2)

fx[u_, v_] := If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, a[u] + c[u] Cos[v + Pi], a[u] + c[u] Cos[u] Cos[v]];
fy[u_, v_] := If[Pi < u < 2 Pi, b[u], b[u] + c [u] Sin[u]];
fz[u_, v_] := c[u] Sin[v];

ParametricPlot3D[{fx[u, v], fy[u, v], fz[u, v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: klein]

Comment: This looks rather "lumpy" around the larger part of the "horn" once you move to the 3rd and 4th circles.