# How to plot a hole in a hole in a hole?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

There is an image from this [book.(page 22)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098705)

I want to plot it, but I don't know  equation of this surface.

[image]

Anyone have an idea about it and how to plot it with *Mathematica*?

Comment: while interesting, I feel like this is more of a math question on how to parametrize that surface

Comment: You might look at the parametric plot of a Klein bottle, it has similar properties (not the same though).
See this [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118957/my-3d-plot-of-a-klein-bottle-doesnt-look-right).

Comment: You could get a shape of the right topology at least by using `RegionUnion`, `RegionDifference` etc. on a `Sphere`, some `Cylinder`'s, and a torus (as an `ImplicitRegion` perhaps).

Comment: I could not find anything relevant but may be these links are useful. http://www.kleinbottle.com/gallery/Hole-through-a-Hole-in-a-Hole http://www.kleinbottle.com/gallery/Spivak_Hole_Pix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8Rxep2Mkp8                       Especially the video.